Do academic researchers generally not worry about their work infringing on patents? Have there been cases where they wish they had?
My Law SE question Instrument builder in a scientific lab w/ academic funding using a technique described in a patent for research, and for developing new technology covers both

Basic academic research that might employ some device, design, algorithm or process that is arguably covered by some patent held by someone else
Academic research that pursues something that might be patentable, that for a short period of time only used something like that described above.

The answer surprised me. It seems that at least in the US, the only situation where a patent holder can not sue someone for using something that is covered by a patent is if it were solely for amusement, to satisfy idle curiosity, or for strictly philosophical inquiry!
When one carries out research, it can sometimes be complicated, the realities are that several things need to be done in order to get a desired inquiry to yield meaningful information. We build gizmos, implement algorithms, procedures, etc. sometimes gleaned from colleagues or accumulated knowledge or by spontaneous ingenuity and invention, and to my personal knowledge, nobody runs every single thing through an exhaustive patent search and vets it as liability-free.
And yet, if the answers in Law SE are to be believed, there are probably zillions of infringements, many may be trivial, some might even be egregious (from a patent prosecution standpoint).
There are of course several reasons why viable patent prosecutions against academic researchers might not happen.
This is all new to me, so I'd like to ask:
Question: Do academic researchers generally not worry about their work infringing on patents? Have there been cases where they wish they had?
And if so, are there certain fields where it's extremely rare or much more common? For example, a Physics vs a Molecular Biology?
note: I'm focusing on academic research and let's further constrain this to publicly funded research through governmental agencies. Things get murky quickly if it is funded via industrial contract or the researcher is starting a company on the side.

The question is ambiguous as it stands. Even if they WERE "worried", how would a worry necessarily produce a better outcome? They have to submit the paper, do they not? Academia is a balance of worries and successes. My point is that whether or not they had a worry about it, it doesn't necessarily mean they won't publish anyway.

@Snared it seems  that the authors of the three well-received answers are able to draw from both shared experience in academia and what the question is getting at and come to a common-sense understanding of what "worried" means here. Nonetheless, the following gives an example of what someone who was (particularly) worried might do. "...and to my personal knowledge, nobody runs every single thing through an exhaustive patent search and vets it as liability-free". Based on everything on this page, it's pretty clear the question, as-asked, is just fine.

In molecular biology we'd generally assume we were covered by "solely for amusement, to satisfy idle curiosity, or for strictly philosophical inquiry".
There are places however, where we do worry about intellectual property slightly, and that is when a supplier produces a product, covered by a patent, specially designed to be used by researchers in their research.
For example, a common protocol used in molecular biology is the Polymerase Chain Reaction. The patent on PCR itself expired long ago, but a key part of a the protocol is the use of a thermostable DNA polymerases. Companies continue to isolate and produce better, faster, more reliable and more accurate polymerases, and patent the use of them in PCR. These are then sold at a high price - the average lab will use thousands of dollars of polymerase in a year, and every lab uses them.
Once the DNA sequence of the polymerase has been identified, making the polymerase yourself is really not that difficult. As every lab uses such things, you could even imagine departments making it in bulk for all the labs in a department. But most labs don't because they worry that they might land themselves in trouble.

Nice example.  Note though, that their are licenses implied when you buy those polymerases, and if you discover, say, a drug using one of them, the patents on the polymerases don't necessarily encumber the drug that was so developed.  Similarly, lets say production of that drug used a patented machine.  Buying the machine probably gives license, and if it doesn't the drug company would need to negotiate the license, so simply encumbering it does not mean the drug will never see the light of day.

@ScottSeidman - Yes. The worry is not that we use patented products in our research, for which we have a licence. But rather we'd be in trouble for infringing a patent for the act of making our own version of the kit itself, not for the consequences it would have on our own downstream IP (we very rarely have any downstream IP, we are not, in general, IP driven).

For most jurisdictions, patents grant the holder only the right to exclude commercial use. I try to answer using US law, which allows the patent holder to exclude any use of the patented invention.
Since most academic research is not for profit, the question is usually moot. Patent infringement can be constituted using a patented method, but there needs to be some tort. If I, by accident, re-invent a patented method, I can also argue that the patent is invalid because it is obvious and lacks novelty. This means that the patent holder is not incentivized to proceed with a lawsuit that might draw the patent holder's competitors into a fight to invalidate a patent.
In academia, I am not worried about patent violations. In industry, as I was told repeatedly, researchers are told not to  worry about patents in their development of products and methods while they are researching and developing, because they might interpret an existing patent too broadly. Whether their proposal is violating a patent will be decided at a later time by vetting a potential product or procedure with patent lawyers. They are under more restrictions, as companies are worried about them using something licensed under a GNU or similar that disallows the company to claim patents.
Historically, there was an issue with product licenses. There was a famous case (I am quoting from memory so details might be wrong, but I was told this by one party) in which a U Wisconsin (Madison) group compared the performance of several databases. Oracle objected to the publication because publishing performance measurements was excluded according to the Oracle license and because their product did not look very good. This lead to a change in federal law that limited the right to exclude performance evaluation by researchers who had NSF grants.
Another related area, where we do need to worry, is non-disclosure agreements, which we enter often without the advice of a lawyer. A NDA can be very one-sided without being obviously so.
So, in short, in Computer Science and at a university, we tend to not worry about accidentally infringing on a patent, until we start thinking about creating a start-up and commercially using the product of our research.
I would be very interested to know what excluding others from "using" an invention actually means. The goal of the patent system is to prevent others from commercial exploitation, which means that there would be plenty of room for allowed use.
Let me make up an example. Assume that someone holds the patent for "database equi-joins by hashing" (It'a a thing). I think I have an even better way of doing it and to show that this is the case, I implement equi-joins by hashing and my new method and then evaluate both of them with many test-cases. Would this constitute "use"? I would argue that this is not the case, as I am not creating an artifact that relies on equi-joins by hashing, I am merely testing it. Of course, the patent holder in my ficticious example would want to argue that by using the patent I created great harm to the patent holder, because my publication makes the patent useless and might want to sue me for damages. I hope that if this were to succeed, federal law might be changed.

"In industry ... researchers are told not to worry about patents in their development of products and methods": my experience is the exact opposite. My legal department would like me not to read any scientific publications, not to do reviews, not to talk to people at conferences, for fear that our product development could infringe on someone's IP. No, they couldn't tell me how this was supposed to work in practice.

That's not what I meant. I edit.

OK. I will leave my comment up, though, and add this: we are told by our legal department not to look at existing patents, again out of fear we might be contaminated. I guess my bottom line is that life in industry can be quite hard, depending on how far internal enforcement goes.

That is my impression as well, but I think it is more about getting scared by patent claims than about contamination. Of course, your experience is more valid than mine, which is indirect, so by all means, keep your comments.

We were told not to look at patents because the legal damages are different for accidental infringement than for intentional infringement, if you never look you can never knowingly infringe.  If we thought we had something that might be patentable we tossed it over the wall to legal for investigation so we would stay 'pure'. This was at a large computer company 20-some years ago so it might also have just been the culture there.

I believe patents exclude for most uses, not commercial uses.  When people tend to get caught infringing is when they try to commercialize.

That's US law, but not e.g. German law.


are there certain fields where it's extremely rare

I work in sociology, and as you can imagine patents just aren't a thing there...

Sure you missed the patent on logistic regression.

"Method for inducing person A to engage in behavior X..."

This actually makes me curious if facebook and google have filed patents over their specific methods for A/B testing features over a wide audience.
